# Change button value on td click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I currently have a table with blank `<td>`s. Each time a `<td>` is clicked, it changes its background color.
I want to change the value of `rcStatus` button along with the colors.
Here's my current code:

HTML:

```
foreach( //conditionals ){ 
    <td id="changeStatus">
       <input type="button" name="rcStatus" id="rcStatus" value=""/>
    </td>
}
```

javascript:

```
 $('#table #td').click(
   function(){
       var cell = $(this),
       state = cell.data('state') || 'first';

   switch(state){
       case 'first':
       cell.addClass('red');
       cell.data('state', 'second');  
       document.getElementById('rcStatus').value = "missed";
       break;
     // other cases here 
   }
 });
```

The problem is, since my `<td>` is in a foreach statement, the input name is not unique.
So the only button value that changes onclick is the first button in the table.

Anyway I can fix this so that the button that changes is the one inside the `<td>` clicked?
Thanks!

Comment: Are #table and #td an IDs? If not, then change click event to $(table td). Also, is it possible for you to create jsfiddle?

Comment: You need to, at the very least, show representative HTML. Without it we can't see what the relationship between elements is.

Comment: What is your `foreach` conditional?  Is there a `key` or a `value` you can append to your `input` `id` so you can get them accurately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job, but it's bad style to use ids more than once.

```
<script>
    $('#table td').click(
      function(){
          var cell = $(this);
          state = cell.data('state') || 'first';

      switch(state){
          case 'first':
          cell.addClass('red');
          cell.data('state', 'second');
          this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = "missed";
          break;
        // other cases here 
      }
    });
</script>
```

And here a solution in pure Javascript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length;i++ ){
    tds[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var that = this;
        that.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "missed";
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: it still only changes the value of the first rcStatus button. :/

Comment: Sorry my fault. I changed it.

Comment: thank you so much! i've been trying to solve this for two days.

Comment: Hi! I'm now trying to store in a database the rcStatus that I get from the table.. but problem is i'm only able to call the last rcStatus using $_POST[rcStatus]... any idea how this can be done? :) (Or should I make this another question entirely? Sorry, also new to stackoverflow)

Answer (score 3):

change the `id` to `class`.

```
foreach( //conditionals ){ 
    <td class="changeStatus">
       <input type="button" name="rcStatus" id="rcStatus" value=""/>
    </td>
}

$('#table .changeStatus').click(
var that=this;
   function(){
       var cell = $(this),
       state = cell.data('state') || 'first';

   switch(state){
       case 'first':
       cell.addClass('red');
       cell.data('state', 'second');

**update:**

$(that).find('input[type="button"]').val("missed"); 
       //document.getElementById('rcStatus').value = "missed";
       break;
     // other cases here 
   }
 });
```

**update:** assuming the id of the table is `#table`

Comment: assuming this is connected to using multiple rcStatus IDs

Comment: In the question.. I assumed that he has given table an id as #table.

Comment: I have used table as the id of the table, but this still only changes the value of the first button. because as mentioned by Pavlo, i'm using multiple rcStatus IDs.

Comment: you can use $(this).find('input[type="button"]) to fix that. you don't even need to give the rcStatus an ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change button text for all td's click, then

Change

```
$('#table #td').click
```

to

```
$('#table td').click
```

Moreover, use class

```
<td class="changeStatus">
```

and,

```
$('.changeStatus').click
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, the issue that you're having is in selecting the RIGHT button to change the value of in your click handler.  If you can append either the `$key` or the `$value` from your `foreach` conditional to the ID of both the `td` and the `input`, you should be able to select it accurately by retrieving that substring from the `td`'s ID and appending it to the `input`'s.

Alternatively, you could find the `input` from the `td`'s child nodes, either way, you'd have to modify your handling function to receive the event as a parameter.

**in the php**

```
foreach($statuses as $key=>value) {
?>
  <td id="changeStatus_<?php echo $key; ?>">
    <input type="button" name="rcStatus_$key" id="rcStatus_<?php echo $key; ?>" value=""/>
  </td>
<?php
}
```

**in the js**

```
$('#table td').click(function(event) {
  var cell = $(this),
      id = cell.id.split('_')[1],
      state = cell.data('state') || 'first';

  switch(state) {
  case 'first':
    cell.addClass('red');
    cell.data('state','second');
    cell.children('#rcStatus_'+id).val('missed');
    break;
  // case '*':
  }
}
```